# Nuget Package Manager Using Static Path for Package Resolution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, npm, package, nuget

Each time I install a new package via Nuget's extension in VS, it is checking for the existence of the target package in a static location (C:\Users[me]\Documents\Code\Nuget)

[image]

This is an issue when I generate projects, as I cannot check them directly into TFS without editing the .csproj file to resolve dependencies relatively. Those settings are on a package-by-package basis, so it is tedious.

I do not see a difference between my coworker's Nuget/VS2015 install and my own, however, when they add new packages via. Nuget, their manager adds a 'Packages' folder in the project directory. Their project then has relative pathing for Nuget resolution.
[image]

What causes this behavior, and what can I do to resolve it? 
Since neither of us knowingly updated our Nuget settings, what can cause configuration side-effects like this?

Comment: This seems like an issue with your NuGet settings, not with NuGet itself. NuGet has a setting for where it restores packages to. Referenced here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior. I believe if you create the restore location to be within your project, VS will use a project relative path in the csproj files

Comment: @SurelyTheresABetterWay, any update for this issue? Could you get any useful info from my update answer? If not, please let me know for free, I will keep follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What causes this behavior, and what can I do to resolve it? Since neither of us knowingly updated our Nuget settings, what can cause configuration side-effects like this?

You may set the `repositoryPath` in your NuGet.config, you can check below settings in the global config file located in `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`:

```
     <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\Users\Documents\Code\Nuget" />
     </config>
```

If you find it, **please comment it or you can delete.**

Besides, if you are not find it in the global config, you can check this NuGet.config under your solution.

Note: please restart your Visual Studio after modifying the NuGet.config.

**Update:**

You can add a NuGet.config under the solution folder with below setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <config>
      <add key="repositoryPath" value="Packages" />
   </config>
</configuration>
```

[image]

With this setting, NuGet will store the packages under the solution folder.

Comment: I've checked the path you provided, as well as all possible paths in the official Nuget Documentation here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior. None of the configuration files specified a repository path. I also reinstalled the Nuget Extension in VS, and the behavior still persists.

Comment: @SurelyTheresABetterWay, not sure the reason for this weird issue, but you can try to add a nuget.config under the solution folder to resolve this issue. You can refer to the detail info from the update answer.

Comment: this put me on the right path. For some reason, I had never visited that AppData location. I was able to find the configuration file in question, and delete the node that was causing the issue. I then had to do some additional work in the solution XML. I also used your Nuget.config solution to make sure I have a manual override should this occur for anyone in the future. Thanks so much!